# configure catfish search folders

Tags: configuration

I was configuring the catfish search folders, **excluding** the folders in the home, that start with the dot /home/user/.* when I realized that **I have to add them one by one**, it's a pain.
I want to avoid catfish looking in /home/user/.* , is there a way to specify this path?
Also, no configuration files were found.

Thanks

Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS  (xubuntu)
catfish 4.16.3

Comment: sorry, I've done!